# Inserting an element into a Balanced Binary Search tree represented as an array

Tags: time-complexity, binary-tree

I was reading a textbook on Algorithms and they were talking about balanced binary trees. It says if we wanted insertion into the tree to be O(logn) then we cannot express it as an array like a heap. Why does any insert procedure runs in Ω(n) time if the binary search tree is implemented as an array? It doesn't explain any further as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

The insertion of an element into a balanced Binary tree could force a "re-balancing" operation (ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-balancing-binary-search-trees-comparisons/). How hard could be to represent this "re-balancing" in an array? How hard could be if pointers are used instead?